# Operations research book to start with

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research

for somebody having a quite strong background in Mathematics, which are some good books for the domain of Operations research? I guess there are textbooks covering topics like linear and nonlinear optimization, convex optimization and quadratic programming, dynamic programming, multicriterial optimizations (did I miss something?)

Thanks,
Lucian

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to a similar question on the OR Exchange: http://www.or-exchange.com/questions/478/

Comment: A new Stack Exchange website called [Operations Research](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research?referrer=OWU4N2NiYTYwZjFmZmI5ZWZhYWJiMjhkNzM1ZmE0OTRmMDQ0MGEwZDZkNDkyMWQwZGVkMmJkZjBmMGIwOWZlNBgZCXPmgsLCC6pPu9k2lPudCxu0yVijowpCoLPtrJ330) has been approved and is expected to be opened soon.

Answer (score 11):

Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe's book is popular, and available free online:
http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Answer (score 8):

*[Linear Programming](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/LP.pdf)* -- *A Concise Introduction* by Thomas S. Ferguson and other ebooks/lecture notes on *Optimization* listed in [Rod Carvalho's web notebook](http://stochastix.wordpress.com/books/).

Addendum:  The classic and complete book by Hillier and Lieberman *[Introduction to Operations Research](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073017795)*

Answer (score 6):

If you want books that give a broad introduction to operations research (including optimization, queuing theory etc.)

The classics are:

**Operations Research - Ronald Rardin**

**Operations Research - Wayne Winston**

They are excellent from pedagogical point of view.

If you want to get into linear programming, this book is widely regarded to be one of the best:

**Linear Programming - Vasek Chvatal.**

For nonlinear programming:

**Nonlinear programming - Dimitri Bertsekas**

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compilation of books taken from OR-Exchange.

http://industrialengineertools.blogspot.com/2010/08/favorite-operations-research-books-from.html

Answer (score 2):

Winston-Operations Research-Applications and Algorithms is a very good book to start with.

Answer (score 2):

introduction to operation research-**Hillier and Libermann**
They give pretty good motivation for the material being presented