# Good book for Integer/Non-Linear/Stochastic/Dynamic programing [Operations Research]

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, integer-programming, operations-research, stochastic-programming

I am looking for a book that deals with more advanced topics of operations research, like stochastic programming, dynamic programming, non-linear programming and integer-programming.

Most books on operations research that I have found are very introductory, and spend most of the time on regular linear programming and network problems via the simplex and dual methods, and then have like 1 small chapter with an informal treatment of the topics mentioned above. What books studies these in much more detail, both theoretical and practical (i.e. implementation in programming languages + practical applications)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operations research book to start with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/operations-research-book-to-start-with)

Answer (score 1):

I can only partly answer your question. The book "Optimization over Integers" by Dimitris Bertsimas and Robert Weismantel. The book deals with integer programming in general and outlines many approaches how to tackle MIOPs. There is also a rather small section about nonlinear formulations. However, if you want to get a broader overview about nonlinear programming in general, an additional book about the topic would be recommended.