# Reference Request: Open-Access Linear, Non-Linear, etc Optimization Textbooks

Tags: optimization, reference-request, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, big-list

Currently, I am building a book report/reviews in an effort to convince some professors to change their in-class textbooks to free open-access books to reduce the burden of cost unto the students taking their courses, as for example, one of my courses is using [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484519) to teach Deterministic Optimization, and that book costs $\$120$, and there were sizable complaints from students being unable to afford the book for the class. I have found [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20643/1119495) [book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4146/1119495) lists on this site, but only one answer out of the $20+$ had [an open-access, free book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/). Even with the last couple months of looking around online, I've had no success as I only found [one site](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Main_Page) that had open-access optimization theory resources, and it's rather poor for intro learners. Of course there are sites like [this one](https://openlibrary.org/subjects/linear_programming) that promotes book sharing, but the limitations for book accesses limits a whole classroom who are competing with using it as a resource for a single book.

Thus, I am reaching out to here in a request for **strictly** open-access, or free-online$^{[ 1 ]}$, optimization textbooks that are hard to find or not so widely known about.

The following topics are the ones I am looking for:

- Linear Programming
- Non-Linear Programming
- Network Programming
- Constraint Programming
- MIP/Integer Programming

This is ultimately important to me in that cost shouldn't be a barrier for theses fun courses, and thus there should be alternatives that students can use that doesn't destroy their savings, as most optimization textbooks that are good are [quite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470462728) [costly](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Nonlinear+Programming%3A+Theory+and+Algorithms%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471486008), but I am at an absolute loss on finding more than what I have already found, as it's easier to motivate such a change in the department for such classes if there's more options for them to pick from.

---

[1]: Released to the public by the original book author for the purpose of it be used for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete books:

- Sekhon,Rupinder. [Applied Finite Mathematics](https://www.freebookcentre.net/maths-books-download/Applied-Finite-Mathematics.html)
- BORWEIN, JONATHAN M. [CONVEX ANALYSIS AND NONLINEAR OPTIMIZATION](https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CaNo2/cano2f.pdf)
- Aharon and Nemirovski,[LECTURE NOTES OPTIMIZATION I – II](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/Lect_OptI-II.pdf) see more in [nemiroviski's home page](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/)
- [Nonlinear Optimization in Machine Learning](https://web.mst.edu/%7Ehuwen/lectures_Nonlinear_Optimization_in_Machine_Learning.pdf)

Finally chapters of this MIT's textbook:

- [Chapter 13 Nonlinear Programming](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-13.pdf)
- [Chapter 09 Integer Programming](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-09.pdf)
- [Chapter 08 Network Models](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-08.pdf)
- [Chapter 05 Mathematical Programming in Practice](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-05.pdf)
- [Chapter 04 Duality in Linear Programming](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-04.pdf)
- [Chapter 03 Sensitivity Analysis](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-03.pdf)
- [Chapter 02 Solving Linear Programs](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-02.pdf)
- [Chapter 01 Mathematical Programming: An Overview](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-01.pdf)